# Using .cumsum() with multiple conditions to cumulative add up values row by row

Tags: python, dataframe, numpy

This is the list values example I want to use to iterate in data frame named df

```
np_checkList = np.array(['ALPHA', 'BETA', 'CHARLIE','DELTA'])
```

This is the data frame example I want to loop using the values in np_checklist against the column 'NAME'

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([['ALPHA',2,'BUY'],
                            ['BETA',5,'BUY'],
                            ['CHARLIE',3,'BUY'],
                            ['CHARLIE',5,'BUY'],
                            ['DELTA',11,'BUY'],
                            ['ALPHA', 2,'BUY'],
                            ['CHARLIE',8,'SELL']]),
                   columns=['NAME','AMOUNT','TYPE'])
```

Below is the end result I achieved by cumulative summing up the 'AMOUNT' values for each row on 'NAME' condition. For example, if the 'NAME' column value is ALPHA and 'TYPE' is 'BUY', then the code will sum up cumulatively for each row.

Resulting in the 1st row for 'ALPHA' with the value of 2 and the 6th row for 'ALPHA' with the value of 4 under 'ACCUMULATE' column.

```
      NAME  AMOUNT  TYPE ACCUMULATE
0    ALPHA       2   BUY          2
1     BETA       5   BUY          5
2  CHARLIE       3   BUY          3
3  CHARLIE       5   BUY          8
4    DELTA      11   BUY         11
5    ALPHA       2   BUY          4
6  CHARLIE       8  SELL
```

I managed to get the above result with this set of codes below.

My codes tend to be more verbose, due to my old school training I received from coding C. Understand that python has a lot of available API to achieve the result with fewer lines. I have 2 questions to seek guidance to deep dive and explore various ways to solve the problem.

**Question 1:** How do I **use .cumsum()** together with values from 'NAME' & 'TYPE' column  as conditions to perform the cumulative sum of the 'AMOUNT' values and update them in 'ACCUMULATE' column?

**Question 2:** I have this warning after running my code below.
May I know how what causes it and how to resolve this warning?

*SettingWithCopyWarning: A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame
See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
self._setitem_single_block(indexer, value, name)*

```
df["AMOUNT"] = pd.to_numeric(df["AMOUNT"])

cumulativeValue = 0
newAccumulation = []
df['ACCUMULATE'] = ''

for name in np_checkList:
    cumulativeValue = 0
    for counter, row in df.iterrows():
            if (row['NAME'] == name) & (row['TYPE'] == 'BUY'):
                cumulativeValue = cumulativeValue + df.loc[counter]['AMOUNT']
                df.ACCUMULATE.iloc[counter] = cumulativeValue
df
```

Comment: I managed to search through the internet for my question 2 on the underlying reasons for the warning and removing the code line `df.ACCUMULATE.iloc[counter] = cumulativeValue` to `df.loc[df.index[counter], 'ACCUMULATE'] = cumulativeValue` to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
df['AMOUNT'] = df['AMOUNT'].astype(int)
df.loc[df['NAME'].isin(np_checkList) & df['TYPE'].eq('BUY'), 'ACCUMULATE'] = df['AMOUNT']
df['ACCUMULATE'] = df.groupby('NAME')['ACCUMULATE'].cumsum()
print(df)
```

Output:

```
      NAME  AMOUNT  TYPE  ACCUMULATE
0    ALPHA       2   BUY         2.0
1     BETA       5   BUY         5.0
2  CHARLIE       3   BUY         3.0
3  CHARLIE       5   BUY         8.0
4    DELTA      11   BUY        11.0
5    ALPHA       2   BUY         4.0
6  CHARLIE       8  SELL         NaN
```